# How to fix attic door which doesn't shut completely

Tags: attic-door

[Check pictures here](https://tinyurl.com/2x8fj9rw)

My attic door(with ladder) won't shut completely.check link.

I found a couple of discussion forums where the suggestion was to adjust springs. But I don't know
exactly how to do that. Can someone explain with pictures?

Comment: Your picture shows an attic door in the ceiling that is not completely closed. On the other side of the door are springs that act as a counterbalance and keep it closed, those are what need adjusting, it probably has a set on the left an another on the right. I am assuming none of the support structure has been bent or moved. Since all attic doors are not all the same why burn our time taking a guess just post pictures of what you have, it helps us help you.

Comment: Pics of your door as closed as it will get. Then open it and give us an overview pic, then detail pics of the springs & spring mount points. Maybe find the brand name of the door (then search the mfgr to see if they can tell you how to adjust it). Pics straight up each side to see if there's something bent somewhere. The more detail you give, the more likely you are to get a good, detailed answer. The less detail you give, the more likely you are to get wild guesses.

Comment: Maybe the hinges have developed a problem.  Maybe the ladder isn't folding or closing all the way and is getting in the way.   Maybe there is some object keeping it from closing.  Maybe there is a clip or latch to hold it closed that isn't working.   Maybe it is held closed by the force of springs that need adjusting.   You need to do some initial diagnosis.

Comment: Check all the screws/bolts to ensure they are tight.

Comment: @Gil - I shared link to my pictures.

Comment: @FreeMan - I shared link for pictures.

Comment: @jsotola - I provided link to the pictures. Because of size limitations I shared link to my Google drive.

Comment: @jsotola - sorry for that. I didn't realize that upload was still in progress. You can check it now.

Comment: @user2716454 maybe the pivot points are attached too far to back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful with those springs! I got stitches in my head watching my brother monkey with an attic door just like that one. The bar went flying upward and cracked me right in the side of my head. The springs are deigned and attached by the door manufacturer and should be perfectly fine and able to hold the door shut.

The door is rubbing against something. Go into the attic with a good flashlight and examine everything over and over until you find what is hitting where. It could be a combination of things.

It could be the door itself is rubbing the opening. It could be the arms or the springs touching the door. It doesn't take much to keep a cheap attic door from staying all the way shut, but once you get everything straight, the arms not bent, the opening aligned properly with the door, then it should stay shut.

This is a door like any other door. Time and moisture warps and moves things. But unlike a typical wooden door, you cannot shave the door to stop it from rubbing. That's why I mentioned adjusting the hole if needed. The door attaches on the one back. You can insert a shim on one side or the other.

That is another thing: The hinge side of the door could be twisted a little downward. If it is, then the door will not shut all the way. The door cannot go past 90 degrees against the hinge. You can use screws to suck in the top of the framing member that the door is attached to.

**Answer:** Inspect and adjust, but leave the springs attached to the door.

Comment: Good advice above. Don't forget to check for a latching mechanism that might be misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

Mine are similar but not as much opening, springs are OK. Looks like stair rails warped slightly pushing the end open. I added weather stripping foam the fill the gap. I plan to make a small truss to pull the open end of the door closed.

Comment: What's your actual solution here? Weatherstripping? A truss (whatever that means)? Please clarify.

Comment: It is weather stripping at this time.

Comment: Seems that would make the problem worse by introducing more friction and enforcing a gap.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of good advice. Could also be humidity; in the summer months when it gets hot & humid, my front door sticks from expansion. Just something else to consider. possibly You could help it close by forcing it up if that's the issue.

Comment: So "push on it"?

Comment: Yeah as simple as it sounds. My front door as i've said expands in the summer months and I have to use a little force to open and shut it. Obviously I don't mean that you get up on a ladder and shoulder it up with all your might, just see if it will stay up with a little force.

Answer (score 0):

[image]One hack is just to find an old unused key with a hole in it and screw it to the outside door frame 6 inches from the pull string on side of door that won't close(see photo).  Screw it down tightly enough to hold the door closed but loosely enough to turn. Turn key towards door to hold door up. Turn key away from door to allow door to drop.

Door is high and somewhat heavy so a ladder may be required to lift door high enough to turn key. Alternately instead of ladder a rod of some kind(sawed off broom stick handle for example) may be used to push up against the door to fully close it with one hand so you can turn the key with the other hand and get the door to stay closed. This may be more convenient since rod may be left near door and doesn't need to be opened and closed like ladder does.  You can paint the key white to make it less obvious if desired(see photo).  You won't be able to get approval from home inspector but door will stay closed.

Comment: It sounds to me like your suggestion is A) push the door harder to close it, then B) use a door knob to latch it, though you're suggesting using a key(?) instead of a standard door knob... An [edit] to include a sketch and/ or rewording your answer to make it more clear would really help a lot.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Added picture above and revised procedure description.  Thanks for suggestions.